# Displaying reactive UI according to the datatable

Tags: r, shiny

How should I generate reactive UI according to the datatable.

Like

Data FRAME

`count  Number   average
20     50       23          'DOWNLOAD BUTTON','DELETE BUTTON'`

This should continue for all the row.

My code as follows

The `UIoutput` did not help me in achieving what I wanted. How do I place the reactive button inside the `rendertable`?

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'PLEASE UPLOAD THE CSV FILE',
                accept = c(
                  'text/csv',
                  'text/comma-separated-values',
                  'text/tab-separated-values',
                  'text/plain',
                  '.csv',
                  '.tsv'
                )
      ),
      uiOutput("more")
),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
      )
    )
  )
))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    return (input$file1)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    output_table<-read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, 
             sep = input$sep)
    output_table<-process(output_table)
    output_table$action_button<-output$more()
    return(output_table)
  })
output$more<-renderUI({
      return (actionButton("but","butt"))
  })
})
```

Comment: What is the version of `RSelemium` and Firefox?

Comment: Is there a command to find those? Please help. I'm a starter in R

Comment: `packageVersion("RSelenium")`